# Why I Can't See MySQL Logs in a Time Range?

Tags: mysql, log, mariadb

I am using Mariadb Galera 3-Cluster replication and yesterday I faced a lot of db exceptions on applications. So the applications wanted to insert data to db but some of data could not be inserted. The first fail came on 13:22:05 and the last fail came on 13:39:45. When I looked at /var/log/mysql on primary and secondary galera cluster I opened and read all the log data files with name "mariadb-bin.0000xx" but I could not see any record between of these times. Why are these logs loss or what must be happened? Is it a common issue or a special issue?

The operations system is Ubuntu 18.04

The Mariadb version is 10.4.13

Comment: The `mariadb-bin.0000xx` files are not meant to be read by humans, but by machines. You want to look in `/var/log/mysql` for the error logs. I'm sure you will find plenty there if the system was unavailable for 15 minutes.

Comment: @Matigo I wrote wrong. I am looking at /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.0000xx and can't find logs between spesific times.